# Terraform enclose string in single quote

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

In my terraform code: ( 0.15.x )

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "keycloak_service" {
    metadata {
        name      = "balab-service"
        namespace = "project-ns
        annotations = { 
         "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-interval-seconds" = trim("'60'", "\\"")
        }
    }
spec {
....
...
```

In EKS/kubectl Service

I keep seeing

> alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-interval-seconds:
> **"'60'"**

> $ terraform console
>
> - trim("'60'", "\"")
> - "'60'"

I expect

> alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-interval-seconds:
> **'60'**

Comment: You can't do this. Single quotes are not supported for strings. What's wrong with using just 60?

Comment: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/#healthcheck-interval-seconds

Comment: above document expects annotation value to be in single quotes. If you have any other way it would very heplful for me. Works when in enclosed in single quotes

Comment: So `metadata` is actual TF code, or some multiline string? Can you provide complete example?

Comment: Edited the content

Comment: @BalaB they are expected to be yaml string literals, it does not matter how you get those. Yaml's `'200'` is identical to `"200"`. So in your case just use the `"60"` value in terraform.

Comment: You can't use single quotes in TF. You either have to use `"'60'"`, `"60"` or `60` .

Comment: It seems from the Terraform provider code that these values are ultimately handled by the Kubernetes Go SDK, and so I'm not sure exactly what format the SDK is expecting, but if it's expecting the result to be valid YAML then one way to achieve that would be to pass your value to Terraform's `jsonencode` function and use the result. (YAML is a superset of JSON, so a `jsonencode` result is also valid YAML).